# Why does OS X Yosemite - Disk Utility has no options for me?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

[image: This is what my Os X Yosemite, Disk Utility look like]

I want run a First Aid on my hard drive, but Disk Utility does not allow me to provide permission to do this.

System Information
MacBook Pro 2012(MD101)
Running Yosemite

Comment: @Allan Not sure, doesn't seem like it immediately to me.

Comment: Have you tried booting into your recovery partition?

Comment: Not sure, am new to the technical side of Mac, I am feeling my Mac is too slow, takes almost 2 minutes to open any app, so I thought to run First Aid and see how it works, if you have any other idea to make it work better?

Comment: @Allan Different situation though, here it's the boot drive.

Comment: @MaheshBabu Hold down alt while rebooting your Mac and then select the recovery partition.

Comment: General rule is, you cannot work on the drive you are booted from. That said, you appear from your picture to have the First Aid option available, what happens when you click it?

Comment: As per the blogs I read, we need to provide check and fix permission to run First Aid, I don't see options to do these

Comment: Were those blogs, perhaps, written long before Yosemite came out?

Comment: This is Capitan's Disk Utility interface and **not** Yosemite's!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my mac on me, but I remember this happening to me in the past. See, I may be wrong, but I don't remember seeing those options available for me on my primary partition. Now, if you are trying to access DiskUtility from within the recovery partition OS, then you should be able to see all options. I highly doubt MacOS would let you erase or partition a primary partition (exception: the bootcamp app), while it's in use by the OS.

You can always run the first-aid, but not modify the partition table on the existing drive (while being used as the primary OS storage) without messing something up (e.g., from within Terminal)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Disk Utility.app provided in newer systems (≥ 10.11.0) doesn't allow you to repair permissions anymore.

Here are the different interfaces:

10.10 (Yosemite):

[image: Disk Utility Yosemite]

compared to 10.11 (El Capitan):

[image]

To verify or repair permissions in El Capitan you have to use the Terminal and either enter:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /
```

or

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs /
```

You may also do this in El Capitan's Recovery Mode after opening Terminal (in the menubar Utilities > Terminal) by entering:

```
/usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs --volume /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

or

```
/usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

Compared to non-Recovery Mode you have to specify your standard system volume (i.e.  --volume /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD instead of / – the name of your main volume may differ though).

To get help enter:

```
/usr/libexec/repair_packages --help
```

---

Additionally: you can simply hit the First Aid button even booted to El Capitan's main system volume – it's not greyed out! – and at least verify the volume.

Comment: @MaxRied The second comment of Mahesh Babu suggests this.